Induced representation and Frobenius reciprocity
I am having a point of confusion when trying to understand the induced representation. My main sources are Bushnell & Henniart's "Local Langlands for GL(2)" (defn in 2.4 on pg 17) and Bump's "Automorphic forms and Representations" (defn in 4.1 on pg 399).
Aside from the first book also requiring smoothness, both define representations and the induced representation as follows:

A representation of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$ is a homomorphism $\pi: G \to GL(V)$.

Given a subgroup $H \subseteq G$ and a representation $(W, \sigma)$ of $H$, the induced representation is the vector space $X$ of function $f: G \to W$ satisfying $f(hg) = \sigma(h)(f(g))$. The action of $G$ on $X$ is given by right-translation on the argument of the function, i.e. $(\Sigma(g)f)(x) = f(xg)$, and the representation is called $Ind_H^G \sigma$.


That the action is given by right-translation to me seems to suggest that $\Sigma$ is an anti-homomorphism from $G$ to $GL(X)$, i.e. that the above is a right-action. That's all fine with me, and I am aware of how to turn a right-action into a left-action by taking inverses.
However, what trips me up is the following statement of Frobenius reciprocity: $$Hom_G(\pi, Ind_H^G \sigma) \xrightarrow{\sim} Hom_H(\pi|_H, \sigma)$$
The map is given in one direction by composing $\phi$ on the left hand side with the map $\alpha_\sigma: Ind_H^G \sigma \to W$ given by $f \mapsto f(1)$, and in the other direction by sending $\phi: V \to W$ an $H$-homomorphism to $\phi_\star$ defined by $\phi_\star(v)(g) = \phi(\pi(g)v)$.
That $\phi_\star(v)$ is a function satisfying $f(hg) = \sigma(h)(f(g))$ is immediate from the fact that $\phi$ is a map of $H$-representations, and that $\pi$ and $\sigma$ both act on the left, i.e. are homomorphisms to $GL(V)$ and $GL(W)$ respectively.
However checking that $v \mapsto \phi_\star(v)$ is compatible with the $G$-action on both sides works by $$\phi_\star(\pi(g)v)(g') = \phi(\pi(g'g)v) = \phi_\star(v)(g'g) = (\Sigma(g)\phi_\star(v))(g')$$
But then this confuses me as to what $Hom_G(\pi, Ind_H^G \sigma)$ means, as $\pi$ has a left $G$-action and $Ind_H^G \sigma$ has a right $G$-action, and the proof doesn't work when I take the corresponding left-action by $\Sigma(g^{-1})$. In other words, $\phi_\star$ seems to intertwine between a homomorphism to $GL(V)$ and an anti-homomorphism to $GL(X)$.
Is this something I should live with, or is there a way to fix this so that all representations are really given by homomorphisms? If this is just a feature to live with, then does the category $Rep(G)$ contain both homomorphisms and anti-homomorphisms?

The action of $G$ on $X$ doesn't seem to me to be an anti-homomorphism. $(\Sigma(g)(\Sigma(h)f))(x)=(\Sigma(h)f)(xg)=f(xgh)=(\Sigma(gh)f)(x)$.

So the action defined really is a left-action, and everything is fine.

I can't believe I missed this, thanks for the help!
